# Unimodal discrete distribution

Tags: probability

How do I prove that the following discrete distribution is unimodal (in the sense that it has only one local maxima)?
\begin{align}
  & P(X=k)=\left. \frac{1}{k!}\frac{{{d}^{(k)}}}{dz}\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}{(p{_i}+q{_i}\cdot z+r{_i}\cdot {{z}^{2}})\ } \right|\ z=0 \ 
 & for\quad k:0,1,...,2n \ 
\end{align}
for any $n\ge 1$, where for each $i ,\quad 0<p{_i},q{_i},r{_i}<1,\quad p{_i}+q{_i}+r{_i}=1,\quad$
and it is never the case that $p{_i}>q{_i}<r{_i}$.

Comment: You take a product over $i$, but there's no $i$ there. Is that what you want?

Comment: In general, look at the _ratio_ $\frac{P\{X=k\}}{P\{X=k-1\}}$ as a function of $k$. Typically, you will find that the _ratio_ $> 1$ for $k \leq M$ and the _ratio_ $ < 1$ for $k > M$; meaning that $P\{X=k\}$ as a function of $k$ increases as $k$ increases, had a peak at $k = M$ and decreases thereafter.  So $M$ is the location of the mode.

Comment: Is the question being asked the following:  Let $Y_i$, $ 1 \leq i \leq n$, be $n$ i.i.d. discrete random variables taking on values $0, 1, 2$ with probabilities $p$, $q$, and $r=1-p-q$ respectively, and let $X = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$.  Prove that the probability mass function of $X$ is unimodal.

Comment: It would be more usual to have  $0\le p,q,r$ and $p+q+r=1$ if these are to be probabilities.   It does not really matter, since it only produces a constant, which does not affect unimodality.

Comment: @Gerry: If Dilip's second comment is correct, then this is a trinomial RV so you can replace the product with a power.

Comment: Thanks @Dilip - I corrected the question, please follow-up.

Comment: @Dilip, I added another condition...

Comment: $(p,q,r) = (0.7,0.2,0.1)$ is such that the condition $p > q < r$ does not hold.  Is that acceptable, or do you want $q > \max\{p,r\}$ to hold so that $q$ is the mode?

Comment: No, my condition is sufficient (q does not need to be the mode of the distribution at n=1).

Answer (score 1):

If there are no further conditions on $p$, $q$ and $r$ apart from $0<p,q,r<1$ then this does not look correct.

Let $n=2$, so  $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}{(p+q\cdot z+r\cdot {{z}^{2}})\ } = p^2 + 2pq z +(q^2+2pr)z^2+ 2qr z^3+r^2z^4$ and the probabilities are $p^2, 2pq, q^2+2pr, 2qr, r^2$.

Now take $p=0.4$, $q=0.1$ and $r=0.5$.  So the probabilities become $0.16,0.08,0.41,0.10,0.25$ and this is not a unimodal sequence.

Perhaps you need an additional condition that $p,q,r$ is unimodal.

Comment: I corrected the question, please follow-up.

Comment: Henry's counterexample still applies. (An even simpler version is $n=1$, same $p$, $q$, $r$.)

Comment: Thanks @Didier, I added the additional condition Henry implied.

Comment: @DidierPiau "even simpler version..."  Actually the OP did say $n > 1$.  But, I suppose unimodal could be taken to mean having a unique global maximum, which Henry's sequence does have, rather than monotone increasing up to the maximum and monotone decreasing thereafter.

Answer (score 1):

**Work in progress** Uncompleted proof of a special case of the desired result.

Let us call a sequence $(a_0, \ldots, a_n)$ as *unimodal* with mode
$M$ if it enjoys the property that
$$a_0 < a_1 < \cdots < a_{M-1} < a_M > a_{M+1} > \cdots > a_n$$
where $1 \leq M < n$.

Let $\{Y_i\}$, denote a sequence of  be n i.i.d. discrete random variables 
taking on values $0,1,2$ with probabilities $p$, $q$, and $r=1−p−q$ 
respectively where we assume that $p < q > r$ so that $(p,q,r)$ is
a unimodal sequence with mode $1$.  Define $X_n = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$.
Then, $X_n$ is a discrete random variable taking on value
$i$ with probability $p_n(i)$, $0 \leq i \leq 2n$.

**Claim:** The sequence
$(p_n(0), p_n(1), \ldots, p_n(2n))$ is unimodal.

We prove the claim by induction.

**Basis:**  The result holds for $n = 1$ since we have assumed that
$(p_1(0), p_1(1), p_1(2)) = (p,q,r)$ is unimodal.

**Induction hypothesis:** $(p_n(0), p_n(1), \ldots, p_n(2n))$ satisfies
$$p_n(k) > p_n(k-1) ~\text{for}~ 1 \leq k \leq M_n, ~~
p_n(k-1) > p_n(k)~\text{for}~  M_n < k < 2n.$$

Now consider the sequence $(p_{n+1}(0), p_{n+1}(1), \ldots, p_{n+1}(2{n+2}))$.
Since
$$p_{n+1}(k) = p_n(k)\cdot p + p_n(k-1)\cdot q + p_n(k-2)\cdot r$$
(where we use $p_n(-2) = p_n(-1) = p_n(2n+1) = p_n(2n+2) = 0$), we have
that for $1 \leq k \leq M_n$, 
$p_{n+1}(k) -p_{n+1}(k-1)$ is the sum of three positive terms and therefore
$(p_{n+1}(0), p_{n+1}(1), \ldots, p_{n+1}(M_n))$ is an increasing
sequence.  Similarly, for $M_n +2 \leq k \leq 2n+2$,
$p_{n+1}(k) -p_{n+1}(k-1)$ is the sum of three negative terms and therefore
$(p_{n+1}(M_n+2), p_{n+1}(M_n+3), \ldots, p_{n+1}(2n+2))$ is a decreasing
sequence.

- If $p_{n+1}(M_n) < p_{n+1}(M_n+1) < p_{n+1}(M_n+2)$, then
  $(p_{n+1}(0), p_{n+1}(1), \ldots, p_{n+1}(2{n+2}))$ is unimodal with
  mode $M_n+2$.
- If $p_{n+1}(M_n) < p_{n+1}(M_n+1) > p_{n+1}(M_n+2)$, then
  $(p_{n+1}(0), p_{n+1}(1), \ldots, p_{n+1}(2{n+2}))$ is unimodal with
  mode $M_n+1$.
- If $p_{n+1}(M_n) > p_{n+1}(M_n+1) > p_{n+1}(M_n+2)$, then
  $(p_{n+1}(0), p_{n+1}(1), \ldots, p_{n+1}(2{n+2}))$ is unimodal with
  mode $M_n$.

All that remains to prove unimodality of $(p_{n+1}(0), p_{n+1}(1), \ldots, p_{n+1}(2{n+2}))$ is to show that the case
$$p_{n+1}(M_n) < p_{n+1}(M_n+1) > p_{n+1}(M_n+2)$$
cannot occur.  Compare to the OP's $p > q < r$ is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks, @Dilip. This is indeed (uncompleted) proof of a special case of my problem - what about the general case where only p>q<r is not allowed...? In my simulations Xn is always unimodal under that sole condition, for any n.

Comment: BTW, @Dilip, Your final double inequality line for the 4th possibility is a typo I think - it should read ...>...<..., in the form of p>q<r.